# Как сериализовать и десериализовать данные из бинарного файла в разных проектах?

Tags: c#, сериализация

Столкнулся с проблемой, что нужно записать данные в бинарный файл в одном проекте, а считать их из другого проекта. При попытке это сделать программа выдала ошибку: "Необработанное исключение типа "System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException" в mscorlib.dll

Дополнительные сведения: Не удалось найти сборку "Discount1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"."

Привожу код, где я записываю данные в файл.

```
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    FileStream fs;
    fs = new FileStream("2.dat", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write);
    formatter.Serialize(fs, shoppers);
    fs.Close();
    Console.WriteLine("#МАСССИВ ОБЪЕКТОВ СЕРИАЛИЗОВАН#");
```

Теперь код, где считываю данные из другого проекта, перед этим перенес файл с данными из старого проекта в новый:

```
 BinaryFormatter formatter1 = new BinaryFormatter();
        FileStream fs1;
        fs1 = new FileStream("2.dat", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        Nodes[] shoppers1 = (Nodes[])formatter1.Deserialize(fs1);
        foreach (Nodes n in shoppers1)
        {
            Console.Write(n.Name + " ");
            Console.Write(n.Surname + " ");
            Console.Write(n.Lastname + " ");
            if (n is NewNodes) Console.Write(n.PhoneNumber());
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        fs1.Close();
```

Comment: Вот прям такую ошибку вам выдала программа? о_О

Comment: @VladD, Необработанное исключение типа "System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException" в mscorlib.dll

Дополнительные сведения: Не удалось найти сборку "Discount1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null".

Comment: Окей, это уже ближе к теме. А что реально внутри файла? Загляните. // Не исключено, что вам предстоит reverse-engineering формата записи. Это длинное и сложное занятие.

Comment: @VladD, заглыдвал в файл. Как только сереализовал, сразу и вывел, чтобы проверить. Там набор объектов определенного класса

Comment: Что значит «набора объектов»? Судя по сообщению об ошибке, там какой-нибудь XML?

Comment: @VladD, я записываю в бин файл объекты класса. Потом вывожу их. 
Потом беру и создаю новый проект и хочу в нем считать данные, но не выходит, так как получаю данную ошибку

Comment: А, окей, то есть и там и там _ваш_ код? Это уже намного лучше. Имеет смысл дописать это в вопрос (там под ним есть ссылка «править»), а то видите, уже минусы посыпались. И выложите записывающий и читающий код, это тоже важно.

Comment: @VladD, хорошо, и правда поторопился

Comment: А у вас в `shoppers1` автосвойства вида `public string Name { get; set; }` не используются случайно? Если, да, то нужно сделать нормальные свойства с бэкполями.

Comment: На время написания кода и тестирования работы, чтобы иметь возможность глянуть в кишки сериализованного файла рекомендую изменить временно `BinaryFormatter` на `SoapFormatter`, который пишет в `xml`. Потом, когда все заработает как надо, можно быстро изменить назад на `BinaryFormatter`. Это маленький такой совет.

Comment: У вас в разных проектах случайно не разные сборки библиотек используются? Discount1 может дело в том что сборка используется не как общая библиотека?

Comment: Я думаю, это вам поможет. http://stackoverflow.com/a/9012089/5472058

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь, я создал разные объекты, и в одном считываю, в другом записываю. Поэтому сборки используются разные. Нашел решение - открыть Проект->Свойства и там написать имя проекта, в котором объект был сериализован. Но не помогло

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваша проблема заключается в том, что класс `BinaryFormatter`, который вы используете для сериализации и десериализации в файл, сохраняет полное имя типа вместе с полным именем сборки (*full qualified name*). Соответственно если при десериализации форматтер не обнаруживает эту сборку, то генерируется `SerializationException`. Для того, чтобы десериализовать данные во втором проекте, вам необходимо подключить именно ту сборку, типы которой сериализовались ранее в первом проекте. Если таковой возможности нет, и вы сами *гарантируете* наличие аналогичных определений типов сериализованных объектов в другом проекте, то можно создать биндер, который переопределит имя сборки и типа во время десериализации и передаст нужную информацию форматтеру. Для этого достаточно определить наследника абстрактного класса [System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationBinder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.runtime.serialization.serializationbinder(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
    public class CustomBinder : SerializationBinder
    {
        public override Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
        {
            Assembly currentasm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

            return Type.GetType($"{currentasm.GetName().Name}.{typeName.Split('.')[1]}");
        }
    }
```

и затем после создания экземпляра `BinaryFormatter` присвоить его свойству [Binder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.binder(v=vs.110).aspx) экземпляр созданного биндера:

```
        Proj2.Node node;
        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        formatter.Binder = new CustomBinder();
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("data.bin", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            node = formatter.Deserialize(fs) as Proj2.Node;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

У меня не работало из-за этого `return Type.GetType($"{currentasm.GetName().Name}.{typeName.Split('.')[1]}");`

Поменял 1 на 0, не тот индекс был.

Comment: Вы уверены, что Ваш ответ по теме? :).